# Return row info based on one distinct column value

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I want to return a table that consists of one column that contains only distinct `projectid`, a second column that displays the `max(date)` from within the given date-range and a third column that shows additional information. I'm still really new to sql.

Query:

```
select distinct (a.projectid), versiondate, newvalue 
from a 
   inner join b on a.projectid = b.projectid 
where b.contractor = 'SQA Contractor Company-1' 
  and a.attributename = 'Status' 
  and versiondate between '2014-10-01 00:00:00' and '2014-10-01 23:59:59' 
group by a.projectid, versiondate, newvalue 
order by versiondate
```

What it's returning:

```
projectid  |         versiondate    |  newvalue
-----------+------------------------+--------------------
p27641     |  2014 10 01 12:23:18   | In work         
p27641     |  2014 10 01 12:23:21   | In billing      
p27641     |  2014 10 01 12:23:45   | completed          
p19397     |  2014 10 01 12:25:03   | pending review       
p19397     |  2014 10 01 12:25:42   | pending assignment    
p10397     |  2014-10-01 12:26:18   | pending-acceptance
```

What I want it to return:

only the distinct projectid's that represent the most recent `versiondate`. I need to see what the `newvalue` was on the most recent date for each distinct `projectid`.

Trying to put that into words was kind of tough so hopefully I explained my question well. Any help/criticism is accepted.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Check out the [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26786833/revisions) of your question and compare the original post with its current form. Might provide some clues for future questions.

Comment: My original post was atrocious. I will keep what you said in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of question needs to be approached in multiple steps.

First, find the most reason version date for each project, then find the corresponding new value.

```
select a.projectid, a.max_versiondate, b.newvalue
from
    (select a.projectid, max(b.versiondate) max_versiondate
    from   a
    inner join b 
            on a.projectid = b.projectid
    where b.contractor = 'SQA Contractor Company-1'
      and a.attributename = 'Status'
      and b.versiondate between '2014-10-01 00:00:00' and '2014-10-01 23:59:59'
    group by
            a.project id) a 
inner join b
        on b.projectid = a.projectid
       and b.versiondate = a.max_versiondate
```

Another option is to use window aggregate methods to find the max value inline, and filter based on that.

```
select *
from
(
select a.projectid, versiondate, newvalue, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY projectid ORDER BY versiondate DESC) rn
from a 
   inner join b on a.projectid = b.projectid 
where b.contractor = 'SQA Contractor Company-1' 
  and a.attributename = 'Status' 
  and versiondate between '2014-10-01 00:00:00' and '2014-10-01 23:59:59' 
group by a.projectid, versiondate, newvalue 
order by versiondate
)
where rn = 1
```

both should give you the same results, it's a matter of your indexing and table size to see which is most effective.

Comment: Wow. Option 2 worked on the first try! Took me a minute to understand what was going on but it does exactly what I'm looking for it to do. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

This can be simpler with the Postgres-specific [**`DISTINCT ON`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT).

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a.projectid)
       a.projectid, b.versiondate, b.newvalue 
FROM   a 
JOIN   b USING (projectid)
WHERE  a.attributename = 'Status' 
AND    b.contractor = 'SQA Contractor Company-1' 
AND    b.versiondate >= '2014-10-01 0:0'
AND    b.versiondate <  '2014-10-02 0:0' 
ORDER  BY a.projectid, b.versiondate DESC;
```

The SQL-standard `DISTINCT` folds duplicates on the whole row. As an extension to this Postgres implemented `DISTINCT ON` to fold duplicates on *selected* columns. For other columns in the `SELECT` list the value from the (consistent) first row is picked, defined by `ORDER BY`, or arbitrary if not well-defined.

You had an misleading halfbreed of both constructs. The parentheses in your query would make sense in combination with `DISTINCT ON`, but hardly die `DISTINCT`. Detailed explanation:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

#### Other points

- You don't need `GROUP BY` in this case.
- Ranges on timestamps are typically best expressed with including lower and excluding upper bound. `BETWEEN .. AND` includes both bounds and is not good for this:

  - [Select a date range from a timestamp column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414222/select-a-date-range-from-a-timestamp-column/7420421#7420421)
- Since you picked meaningful column names, you join conveniently join with the [`USING` construct](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM).